# Git pull when multiple remotes are confiured

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I have two remotes, one pointing to the main repo and another to the fork on github. When i do just a `git pull` , where is the data pulled from ? Is it from the main repo or the fork ? I must add that the fork is out of sync with the main repository...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

`git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`

> <repository> should be the name of a remote repository as passed to git-fetch[1]. <refspec> can name an arbitrary remote ref (for example, the name of a tag) or even a collection of refs with corresponding remote-tracking branches (e.g., refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*), but usually it is the name of a branch in the remote repository.
>
> Default values for <repository> and <branch> are read from the "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch as set by git-branch[1] --track.

So: Check which remote your local branch is tracking with `git branch --vv`, and that will tell you which remote you will pull from.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke "Pull Dialog" via **VCS | Git | Pull** and pick the repo to Pull from under drop-down list "Remote"

Comment: yes, i can see the list, but im not sure if what looks like a selection is really one, or just a text highlight because it seems to work without selection. I need to try it out.